# Bayesian analysis for multiple unknowns

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I've encountered this problem but my stats is rusty and I've been having trouble formalizing it enough to tackle it.

I have something like a family tree where each node in the tree has two parents and can be one of two parents for some other node(s) (or not if it's a leaf node).  Each node is either red or black and inherited its color from one of its parents, chosen randomly with equal probability of being from either parent.

Each node has a prior probability for being red (based on some educated guesses).  I'm then told the color of a certain subset of nodes.  I want to update my tree with posterior probabilities given the new information.  That is, the nodes I'm given have their prosterior probabilities to be red set to either 1 or 0 and the unknown node probabilities are updated to incorporate the new information.

As an example, this tree has some known nodes (the ones colored red or black) and some unknown nodes (the blank ones).  I want to update the probabilities of the unknown nodes given the known nodes.

[image: example tree]

This feels like an obvious problem for Bayesian analysis, and it's very similar to something like [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1867463/pdf/JMD006000001.pdf), but the simultaneous nature of updating the posterior probabilities for all nodes in the tree is confusing me and I haven't figured out how to set up the update.

Comment: I would have thought you could generate all the possibilities for the grandparents, then for the parents (the grandparents' children) and then the children (grandparents' grandchildren) taking account of the probabilities. Then throw away all the cases that do not fit the given information, reset the probabilities for the remaining families so they add up to $1$ and thus get posterior probabilities for the unknown individuals.

Comment: With an quick unchecked attempt, if the grandparents were originally independently equally likely to be red or black, this suggested to me posterior probabilities of being red of $0.4$ for the third grandparent, $0.3$ for the left parent, $0.1$ for the right parent, and $0.2$ for each of the two other children,

Comment: I *think* enumerating all the possibilities and finding the fraction of them consistent with a given unknown node being red or black would work to find the conditional probabilities, but you'd have $2^N$ different trees to consider for $N$ unknown nodes which seems excessive.  And even with the conditional probabilities for each node in hand it's not immediately obvious to me how to find the posterior probabilities.  Is it a system of simultaneous equations or can you get away with solving for each node one at a time in isolation?

Comment: There is something a bit strange from your formulation. You say that each node inherits their color from their parents with equal probability and then say that each node has a prior probability of being black or red. Do you mean each root node, for the latter?

Comment: If you accept approximate answers. You can do some rejection sampling scheme: sample from the root node priors (if their color is not given), sample the nodes from the rest of the tree, and accept only those that match the observed data.

Comment: @Sergio Good point.  If you imagine the tree is sampled from a much larger population of nodes that don't connect to the tree, the prior probability is the proportion of nodes colored red in that larger population.  I think it's the same as saying the nodes without parents have priors from the general population and the other nodes inherit their probabilities from their parents, but I could be wrong.